# Can I set working directory in pycharm run/debug configuration witch something like $FileDir$?

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I am trying to set my Pycharm run/debug configuration for robot framework tests. I would like to create configuration, where I can run any robot file in any directory with run/debug button.

`$FileName$` works when set to Parameters field

But the working directory works only when the path is real. I've tried `$FileDir$` and `$FilePath$`. None of those worked.

Note: I know about File->Settings->External Tools option, but I believe, there is also way via run/debug configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so setting it to directory of script worked. So If you select script in first field, then this folder is automatically set for you. It worked for me like this.